# How can I send characters at specific delays to a telnet address?

Tags: bash, telnet

Note: i have not included exact addresses for privacy reasons.

Here is the procedure I would like to be able to do:

I am first proceeding into telnet as follows.

```
telnet <myaddress> <myport>
```

Then, the following message appears, followed by a flashing cursor

```
Trying <some address>...
Connected to <cloud address>.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

At this stage, I would like to enter Two Carriage Returns (ASCII 13 or '\r') spaced 100 milliseconds apart.

--

How can I achieve this while in telnet mode that does not require me to manually hit Carriage Return at the right timing?

Comment: Are you familiar with expect?

Comment: You could write a script that echoes what you want, with appropriate timing, and then pipe its output to `telnet`.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the output of a command or script that outputs the characters you want with appropriate timing.

```
{ printf '\r'; sleep .1; printf '\r'; } | telnet <myaddress> <myport>
```